# Could a Prism Service Exposing IObservable<T> eliminate the need for IEventAggregator?

Tags: wpf, system.reactive, prism-4

Can we eliminate the need for `IEventAggregator` with something like this:

```
namespace MyApp.Shared.Services
{
    public interface IMyPrismService
    {
        string GetApplicationProperty(string key);
        void SetApplicationProperty(KeyValuePair<string, string> pair);
        int GetMyWidgetCount();
        IObservable<IEnumerable<MyOtherWidget>> ReactToMyOtherWidgetsLoaded();
    }
}
```

??

When this pattern is seen as useful (even though `IEventAggregator` is cool), how would one set this up using Reactive Extensions?

Comment: I might want to consider this: http://joseoncode.com/2010/04/29/event-aggregator-with-reactive-extensions/

Comment: Easy enough to do, but why?